# "has scientists excited" or "has excited scientists"?

Tags: adjectives, past-participles, complements, perfect-aspect, causative-verbs

I saw the following on the Facebook page of *Time*. Is "has scientists 
excited" or the perfect version "has excited scientists" correct?

What's the difference if both are correct?

> The recent discovery of a subterranean sea, deep inside earth, 
>   has scientists excited.

Comment: They are both correct, with the *Time* rendering striking a less formal register.

Answer (score 6):

Based on my own feeling:

"has scientists excited" sounds more like they have been and still are excited

While

"has excited scientists" sounds like they were excited and might not be anymore.

Neither are incorrect though.

Comment: When you excite a scientist, the scientist eventually falls back to its ground state.

Comment: Neither _is_ incorrect.

Comment: @200_success Neither *is* you.